# How to solve exception error when consuming Microsoft Sql Server Reporting Services (SSRS) 2005 from Delphi XE7

Tags: delphi, reporting-services

I am trying to create a sample Delphi XE7 desktop app that will connect to SSRS 2005 web service but every time I try to call LoadReport web method, the following error is shown:
[image: WS Error]

This is what I have done so far:

1. Create a desktop app.
2. Import WSDL for ReportExecution2005 and  ReportService2005.
3. Create a button that call the web service based on the code shown
   [here](http://www.devsuperpage.com/search/Articles.aspx?G=2&ArtID=106842). The web service locations as well as report are hardcoded for
   simplicity purposes.
   This is the code snippet from the link:

   HTExec :=  tHttpRio.Create(nil);

   rsExec := GetReportExecutionServiceSoap(False, ExecURL, HTExec);

   // Load the selected report.

   LRParams.Report := 'ReportName';

   LoadParamsResponse := rsExec.LoadReport(LRParams); //here it fails

Note: I have already created a .NET win form app (VS2010 and VS2013) that consumes this web service without any issues, thus I know the web service and report to render are working OK. Sadly our requirements is for a Delphi solution, My educated guess is that the WSDL importer generated code is not correct and somebody out there may have come across with this issue before and know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick search for "`http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices/LoadReport`"
and found [this](http://sqllocaldata.blogspot.be/2012/02/loadreport-soapexception-help-needed.html).

If it applies to you as well, it may be the case you're calling the service on an incorrect URL, use the one with `ReportExecution2005.asmx`in it, not `ReportService2005.asmx`

(There's a lot more [here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=SoapAction%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.microsoft.com%2Fsqlserver%2F2005%2F06%2F30%2Freporting%2Freportingservices%2FLoadReport%22))

Answer (score 0):

To find out differences between the Delphi version and the working version, use a HTTP proxy (Fiddler2) to capture the SOAP HTTP traffic in both setups.

If you have no access to the working environment, use SoapUI to create SOAP requests.

Comment: I am in the process of doing that, is there any special part of the packet I should compare using Fiddler or SoapUI?